# Matlab vectorization with if and for loops using ODE45 to integrate

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vectorization, nested-loops, ode45

I am interested in optimizing the speed of my code and when using "Run and Time" this is the function in my code that greatly impacts speed, but I have a hard time conceptualizing how to vectorize this function properly as I usually just do looping, in the attempt I've made I run into an error as it is also used in an integration, my original function is as follows and does not result in an error

```
function [dotStates] = ODEFunc(t,states,params)
%ODE function
% Loading in and assigning the variables from parameters
K = params(1);                                                             
N = params(2);
nn = params(3);
% magnitude of the coupling based on the number of neighbours
kn = K/nn;
w = params(4:end);
dotStates=states;
    % For each oscillator
    for i=1:N
        % Use the oscillators natural frequency
        dotStates(i) = w(i);
        % For j number of neighbours
        for j=(i-nn):(i+nn)
            % neighbour number is positive and shorter than # of oscilators
            if (j > 0) && (j < length(dotStates))
                dotStates(i) =  dotStates(i) + (kn * sin( states(j)-states(i) ));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I've tried following the mathworks vectorization guide: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

My attempt so far has been to follow some of the inputs of what they use, such as using a mask and have generated following code

```
function [dotStates] = ODEFunc(t,states,params)
%ODE function
% Loading in and assigning the variables from parameters
K = params(1);                                                             
N = params(2);
nn = params(3);
% magnitude of the coupling based on the number of neighbours
kn = K/nn;
w = params(4:end);
dotStates=states;
% Use the oscillators natural frequency
dotStates = w';
% Mask of j states
j = (i-nn):(i+nn);
% neighbours cannot exceed boundaries
j = j(j>0 & j <=length(dotStates));
jstate = states(j);
jstate(numel(states)) = 0;
dotStates =  dotStates + (kn * sin( jstate'-states ));
end
```

I ended up with a vector that is shorter than what is being written to and my solution has been to just add a bunch of zeros to the "jstate" variable to make up for the difference but that does not feel like a proper vectorization and when I run the code I get the following error which is tied to and integration step

> Warning: Colon operands must be real scalars.
>
> In RK_ODE_2411>ODEFunc (line 99)
>     In RK_ODE_2411>@(t,states)ODEFunc(t,states,params)
>     In ode45 (line 324)
>     In RK_ODE_2411 (line 58)

the function is in turn used in the following segment for the integration using ODE45

```
%% Integration via ODE45
for K = 0:.1:Klen
    params(1) = K;
    K_count = K_count+1;
    nn_count = 0;
    for nn = nnlen:nnlen
        params(3) = nn;
        % index counter
        nn_count = nn_count+1;
        % 6th order runge kutta

        sol(K_count,nn_count) = ode45(@(t,states) ODEFunc(t,states,params),tSpan,init,options);
    end
end
```

where line 58 is

```
sol(K_count,nn_count) = ode45(@(t,states) ODEFunc(t,states,params),tSpan,init,options);
```

EDIT: line 99 in ODEFunc is

```
j = (i-nn):(i+nn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
% For each oscillator
for i=1:N
    % For j number of neighbours
    j=(i-nn):(i+nn);

    % neighbour number is positive and shorter than # of oscilators
    lg = (j > 0) & (j < length(dotStates));
    dotStates(i) =  w(i) + sum(kn * sin( states(lg)-states(i) ));
end
```

the most important is though that `dotStates` won't be larger than `stats`, since this would force matlab to rearrange its memory, which slows down the code enormously.

Comment: Indeed, the code needs an assertion that `length(states) == N`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
The error is gone and it feels so good going from 528 seconds down to 18 seconds run time.
It does feel like a bummer being so close when i also originally had the i=1:N for loop some time before asking here.